# Showing segmentation fault(core dumped) vigenere cipher

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm doing the pset for cs50 and this keeps showing segmentation fault no matter what I do.

I'v tried various stuff but it keeps showing the same thing.

This is the code for the vigenere cipher I'm trying to implement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,string argv[]){

 if(argc == 2){

 //check if text
 if(isalpha(argv[1])){

 //key
 string num = argv[1];
 int num_length = strlen(num);

 //convert key to lower for easier stuff,dont want to repeat for higher too
 for(int i = 0;i < num_length;i++){

  if(isupper(num[i])){
    num[i]= tolower(num[i]);
  }

 }

 //ask for name
 printf("Line to be encoded please :- \n");
 string name = GetString(); 

 //main stuff
 for(int i=0,n = strlen(name);i < n;i++){

   if(isupper(name[i])){

   //key part
   int keyu = (num[i] - 97) % num_length;

   //converting to alphabetical index
   int alpha_name_upper = name[i] - 65;

   //encoding
   int encoded_upper = (alpha_name_upper + keyu) % 26;

   //converting back to ascii index
   name[i] = encoded_upper + 65;

   }

   if(islower(name[i])){

   int keyl = (num[i] - 97) % num_length;

   int alpha_name = name[i] - 97;
   int encoded_lower = (alpha_name + keyl) % 26;

   name[i] = encoded_lower + 97;

   }

  }

  printf("Encoded line :- %s \n",name);

 } 
 }else{

 return 1;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this keeps showing segmentation fault no matter what I do

Unfortunately, you didn't show us what is inside of `<cs50.h>`, nor what `string` is, nor what `GetString()` does.

If we assume that `string` is a typedef for `char*` (the only thing that makes sense), then this line:

```
if(isalpha(argv[1])){
```

should not compile, since calling `isalpha` on a `char*` makes no sense.

Anyway, *when* you have a core dump, *the very first thing* you should do is  build the program with debug info (with the `-g` option) and run it under debugger (such as `gdb`). This will tell you which line of your program is crashing.

If you are running on a platform (such as Linux) where valgrind is supported, you should run the program under valgrind as well, and it can often tell you *exactly* what's wrong with your program.

Comment: Yeah you're right, once I removed that line of code, it compiled. Anyway Thank you.